# Unable to tunnel through proxy with Apache cxf soap

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, proxy, cxf

I'm trying to call via SOAP over an HTTPS Proxy with Apache CXF.

It's a Java Application running on Cloud Foundry. The Proxy is provided as a Cloud Foundry service. Rest calls are working with via configuration in a RestTemplateCustomizer.

I tried the following (I tried every commended statement without success):

```
    PortType port = cs.getServicePort();
    assert port instanceof BindingProvider;
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, serviceURL);
    //bp.getRequestContext().put("https.proxyHost", endpoint.getHost());
    //bp.getRequestContext().put("https.proxyPort", endpoint.getPort());

    final Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    final HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

    http.getClient().setProxyServer(endpoint.getHost());
    http.getClient().setProxyServerPort(endpoint.getPort());
    http.getProxyAuthorization().setUserName(configProperties.getUser());
    http.getProxyAuthorization().setPassword(configProperties.getPassword());

    //http.getProxyAuthorization().setAuthorizationType("Basic");
    //http.getClient().setProxyServerType(ProxyServerType.SOCKS);

    http.getAuthorization().setUserName(configProperties.getUser());
    http.getAuthorization().setPassword(configProperties.getPassword());
    //http.getAuthorization().setAuthorizationType("Basic");
```

Stacktrace looks like:

2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.mapException(JaxWsClientProxy.java:183)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy288.getConfigurations(Unknown Source)

#

2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: java.io.IOException: IOException invoking https://service.com/services/Service/v1: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1402)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1386)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:673)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:440)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:355)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
   2019-05-16T11:11:53.76+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     ... 131 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I had to set the following flag:

```
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
```